# Mostrar elemento de combobox en un textbox WPF c#, por favor ayuda

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, textbox

Aquí tengo el método que se genera en c#

```
    private void Capitales_SelectedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = Capitales.SelectedItem.ToString();

        tb.Text = "Selection: " + s;
    }
```

En el combobox estoy metiendo una colección "list"
el resultado me aparece así:
ComboBox_MicroDocu.MainWindow+Ciudades, donde Ciudades es mi clase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, no entiendo realmente bien tu pregunta, pero imagino que lo que te ocurre en vez de aparecer el nombre de la ciudad, el TextBox te muestra el nombre de la Clase, que en este caso es Ciudades.

Esto es lo que tienes:

```
private void Capitales_SelectedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = Capitales.SelectedItem.ToString();

    tb.Text = "Selection: " + s;
}
```

Para que te muestre el nombre de la ciudad a través del ToString(), debes SOBREESCRIBIRLO, tal como se ve a continuación, si no lo haces, solo mostrará el nombre de la Clase, debes sobreescribirlo dentro de tu clase Ciudades, simplemente copia y pega esto (supondré para este ejemplo que tienes una propiedad llamada Nombre que almacena el nombre de la ciudad):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Nombre;
}
```

Si NO quieres usar el Tostring() puedes llamar al Nombre directamente, pero tienes que decirle al compilador que ESO que estás llamando es una clase de tipo Ciudades y luego le agregas el ".Nombre".

```
private void Capitales_SelectedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = ((Ciudades)Capitales.SelectedItem).Nombre;
    tb.Text = "Selection: " + s;
}
```

Y si quieres hacerlo más corto puedes declararlo así:

```
private void Capitales_SelectedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tb.Text = "Selection: " + ((Ciudad)Capitales.SelectedItem).Nombre;
}
```

Imagino que tu combobox también muestra ese error, puedes corregirlo de 2 formas.

1) Sobreescribiendo el ToString() que es lo que usan todos los controles que contienen listas para mostrar por defecto.

2) Indicándole al Combobox que muestre el nombre agregando la propiedad DisplayMemberPath y si tiene un ID el SelectedValuePath.

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Nombre" SelectedValuePath="Id">
```

Y ya con eso mejoras tu código.
Un saludo.